# Ubuntu 20.04 only recognizes 8gb of total 16gb RAM

Tags: 20.04, ram

The UEFI/BIOS recognizes the RAM in its entirety.

- CPU: AMD R5 2600
- Motherboard: Asrock B450 Pro BIOS V. P4.10
- RAM: G Skill Ripjaws V Series 2 x 8GB

```
sudo dmesg | grep memory
[    0.000000] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09d02000-0x09ffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20afff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0b000000-0x0b01ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7717000-0xd7717fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7727000-0xd7727fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7c58000-0xd7c98fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xda245000-0xda245fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdb19d000-0xdc691fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdc814000-0xdcc27fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdcc28000-0xdd775fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdf000000-0xdfffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfcffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.004707] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.363035] Freeing initrd memory: 80116K
[    0.363429] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    0.488275] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
[    0.488733] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2712K
[    0.503646] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2008K
[    0.503898] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1192K
[    0.612584] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 4038424 KiB
[    0.612585] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 KiB
[    0.612599] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    0.612599] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
```

```
    sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P4.10
       date: 03/05/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: e
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 1
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 10
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 576KiB
       capacity: 576KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

```
    free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.4Gi       4.6Gi        89Mi       717Mi       4.9Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h`.

Comment: Sure thing, edit applied.

Comment: This seems to be one of those finicky Ryzen/RAM compatibility issues? If solvable it's probably pretty esoteric. I may just need to sell this kit and get one that is officially compatible with my motherboard. Just happened to have these on hand. Kinda wanted ECC anyways. If there is a solution someone is aware of though I'd love to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at P4.10.

**Memory**

*This seems to be one of those finicky Ryzen/RAM compatibility issues?* Maybe.

Reference this [manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B450%20Pro4.pdf), page 23, for correct RAM installation. DIMMS should be installed into slots A2/B2.

**Overclock**

If your CPU or RAM is overclocked, reduce the settings back to default.

Comment: I tried this configuration Ubuntu still only recognized 8GB of RAM. I ensured all slots worked and both sticks of RAM worked. It just doesn't seem to want to recognize both sticks by the time it hits the OS kernel. I even tried funky insertions such as A1 B2. I have also tried OC and non OC'ed.

Comment: @interwebbinitup Google "Ryzen RAM compatibility".

Comment: Yeah, appreciate your effort my friend. It appears the solution is to hire a bunch of low-level software engineers...or buy another kit of RAM that is officially compatible.